# How to override typescript interface property type

Tags: typescript

I have autogenerated typescript file in project api.ts, so I can not change it. This files has interface

```
interface Response {
   data: any;
}
```

how can I override type of data prop, to something like string for example, when I am importing from api.ts?

Comment: How is this interface exported? Does the file have any `import` or `export` statement?

Comment: yes it is exported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches you can take

1. **Augment the Module's Type:**

You can create a folder named `@types` within your `src` directory. Then, inside a file like `module-augment.d.ts` (note the `.d`) or any suitable name, you can use module augmentation to extend the existing Response interface.

```
// src/@types/module-augment.d.ts

import 'module-that-owns-response-interface'; // Import the module

declare module 'module-that-owns-response-interface' {
  export interface Response {
    data: string; // Extend the Response interface
  }
}
```

This will enhance the type of `Response` throughout your project.

2. **Create a New Type:**

You can define a new type that extends the existing `Response` interface, overriding the data property with the desired type.

```
interface NewResponse extends Response {
  data: string; // Override the data property type
}
```

This way, you can use NewResponse where needed.

3. **Generic Type Approach:**

To add more flexibility, you can create a generic type that can adapt to different data types. This could be particularly helpful when the Response object can have varying data types.

```
interface GenericResponse<Data = any> extends Response {
  data: Data;
}
```

This allows you to use GenericResponse with different data types as needed:

```
const response: GenericResponse<string> = { data: 'hello' };
```

#### Considerations:

- If the Response interface was initially defined as any, it's worth investigating why that decision was made and whether there's an opportunity to improve the type definition at its source.
- If you're utilizing a library like axios where the Response type is already defined as a generic, you can directly specify the desired data type when using the type.

Hope it helps!

Comment: "module-that-owns-response-interface" . I do not have it module, it is file in my project, but I can not change it because it is autogenerated.

Comment: In this case, "module" is the same as "file". You are also not supposed to change the original file in either of the suggestions.

Comment: Building on what Parzh said, any file containing an export or import declaration is considered a module. In your situation, you should import the file where the Response type is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, without knowing the rest of your code:

```
type OtherResponse<T> = Omit<Response, 'data'> & {
  data: T;
}
```

or

```
interface OtherResponse<T> extends Omit<Response, 'data'> {
  data: T;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but this is not an options, I would need to change imports every to use OtherResponse